# phonenumbers.PhoneNumber as a FastAPI response_model field

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

FastAPI supports having some (predefined) classes as pydantic model fields and have them be converted to JSON. For example `datetime`:

```py
class MyModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
  created_at: datetime.datetime
```

When used this model would convert `datetime` to/from `str` in the output/input JSON, when used as a response model or request body model, respectively.

I would like to have similar type safety for my own classes:

```py
class MyModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
  phone_number: phonenumbers.PhoneNumber
```

This can be made to work for request body models by using a custom validator but I also need `MyModel` to be convertible *to* JSON. Is this possible to achieve today? Note that I don't control the `PhoneNumber` class so the solution can't involve modifying that class.

Edit: the best I've come up with but still doesn't work:

```py
def phone_number_validator(value: str) -> phonenumbers.PhoneNumber:
    ...

class MyModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
    phone_number: phonenumbers.PhoneNumber

    _validate_phone_number = pydantic.validator(
        'phone_number', pre=True, allow_reuse=True)(phone_number_validator)

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {
            phonenumbers.PhoneNumber: lambda p: phonenumbers.format_number(
                p, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164),
        }
```

This fails in FastAPI with:

```
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'phonenumbers.phonenumber.PhoneNumber'> is a valid pydantic field type
```

Comment: I was about to point it out, but it seems you already posted this in the appropriate [issue tracker](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1186#issuecomment-1256025431).

Answer (score 1):

As you have already noticed, this is a bug in FastAPI. I just created a [PR](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/5429) to fix it.

The `arbitrary_types_allowed` config directive is lost during the processing of the response model.

Until the PR is merged, you can use the workaround of monkey-patching the Pydantic `BaseConfig` like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseConfig

...

BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True

# Your routes here:
...
```

But keep in mind that **independent from this bug** you might also need to adjust the JSON schema for the custom type, if you want the OpenAPI docs to work properly. Arbitrary types are not generally supported by the `BaseModel.schema()` method.

For that you can probably just inherit from `phonenumbers.PhoneNumber` and set a proper `__modify_schema__` classmethod. [See here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#classes-with-__get_validators__) for an example. Though I have not looked thoroughly into [`phonenumbers`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/dev/python/phonenumbers/phonenumber.py).

Check the example code in my PR text, if you want to see how you could implement validation and schema modification on your `PhoneNumber` subclass.

### PS

Here is a full working example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI
from phonenumbers import PhoneNumber as _PhoneNumber
from phonenumbers import NumberParseException, PhoneNumberFormat
from phonenumbers import format_number, is_possible_number, parse
from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseConfig


class PhoneNumber(_PhoneNumber):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: Union[str, PhoneNumber]) -> PhoneNumber:
        if isinstance(v, PhoneNumber):
            return v
        try:
            number = parse(v, None)
        except NumberParseException as ex:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid phone number: {v}') from ex
        if not is_possible_number(number):
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid phone number: {v}')
        return number

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema: dict) -> None:
        field_schema.update(
            type="string",
            # pattern='^SOMEPATTERN?$',
            examples=["+49123456789"],
        )

    def json_encode(self) -> str:
        return format_number(self, PhoneNumberFormat.E164)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    phone_number: PhoneNumber

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {
            PhoneNumber: PhoneNumber.json_encode,
        }


test_number = PhoneNumber(
    country_code=49,
    national_number=123456789
)


# Test:
obj = MyModel(phone_number=test_number)
obj_json = obj.json()
parsed_obj = MyModel.parse_raw(obj_json)
assert obj == parsed_obj

BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True

api = FastAPI()


@api.get("/model/", response_model=MyModel)
def example_route():
    return MyModel(phone_number=test_number)
```